# How to trigger a Jenkins job at boot

Tags: jenkins

When running Jenkins as docker container, some advanced setup may be lost at upgrade (or restart). My typical example is to download wildfly-cli jar into `/var/lib/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/` for [wildfly-deployer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/wildfly-deployer)

I find it easy to implement such setup thanks to a Jenkins job.

And I now face the following question: is there a way to trigger that Jenkins job only once after system/jenkins boot ?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, which might be somewhat hacky: Build a custom docker container based on the original Jenkins container and add an extra step to your docker file.

That extra step would be triggering that Job. Jenkins does have an option to start job externally, e.g., from a script, or in your case from a docker file.

You can rebuild and restart that container and it will run the build once. Would that work for you?

Comment: Docker run command starts Jenkins process itself, then I do not see an easy how to also run a "curl" command to trigger job external from the same container. Maybe Kubernetes or Openshift supports such request invocation (the same way it does health monitoring...)

Comment: You're right, just a RUN in the Dockerfile would not suffice. Maybe overriding the entrypoint might work?

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue:  https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-bash-command-after-startup/21631 They used concatenated bash commands as the entry point.